# Push notifications not sending due to JSON error in server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, parse-platform, push-notification

I cannot figure out why the json is incorrect. I used curl command and it worked perfectly fine. Any reason why this error occurs? I included the error message on the bottom. All other forums are saying to add `/parse` to the end of the server URL, but I have already done that.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("TestNotification", function(request, response){
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.equalTo("appName", "NewApp");

  Parse.Push.send({
      where: query,
      data:{  
          title: request.params.title,
          alert: request.params.alert
      }
    }, { useMasterKey: true })
    .then(function() {
      response.success();
    }, function(error) {
      response.error(error);
  });
});
```

curl
`curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xxxxxxx"  -H "X-Parse-Master-Key: xxxxxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"where":{"channels":{"$in":["testchannel"]}},"data":{"alert": "test push"}}' https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/parse/push`

angular(where I am calling the cloud code)

```
Parse.Cloud.run('TestNotification', {title: "title", alert: "alert"}).then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result);

                }, 
                function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```

Error

`message: 'Received an error with invalid JSON from Parse: Cannot POST /push\n' } } code=141, code=107, message=Received an error with invalid JSON from Parse: Cannot POST /push`

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: the only option how to send PUSH with parse-server is to use Cloud Code function and Masterkey... and call this function with curl is fine...

Comment: @MazelTov I am using the cloud code function and Masterkey

Comment: @SteveMcMeen I am using my parse dashboard and curl to test if the notifications actually send and they do

Comment: @joethemow Please add the curl command to the question.

Comment: @SteveMcMeen I updated my question with the curl command

Comment: Try to use double quotes and escape them too:
\"{\"where\":{\"channels\":{\"$in\":[\"testchannel\"]}},\"data\":{\"alert\": \"test push\"}}\"

Comment: @SteveMcMeen the curl command I put in the question works...It's when I switch to javascript is where the problem occurs.

Comment: Then add the actual code for calling this cloud funciton.

Comment: @SteveMcMeen that's not the problem, the cloud code gets called just fine, it's the code I posted above in the question.

Comment: That's why I'm wondering, I have the exact same code and it works just fine.

Comment: @SteveMcMeen please check out my updated question

Comment: Yeah, do it like this:
var params = {title: "title", alert: "alert"};
Parse.Cloud.run('TestNotification', JSON.stringify(params)).then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result);

                }, 
                function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

Comment: @SteveMcMeen same error, when I do JSON.stringify the input is `Input{}`, but when I don't do JSON.stringify the input is `Input{"title": "title", "alert": "alert"}`

Comment: I'm out of Ideas, even if you hard code a data json on the server code it won't get sent?

Comment: Yup even when I hard code the json data it still does not work.

Comment: Never swnd masterkey over network... masterkey has rights to delete all info from your app... use only master key inside cloud code functions and call those functions without that key!!!

Comment: The master key is used in the cloud code.

Comment: What version of the parse-server is this?

Comment: This is what I have in my package.json `"parse": "~x.x.x",
    "parse-server": "~x.x.x"`

Comment: its "x" that installs the latest version